# Access Row Data to Columns based off Multiple ID Values

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I am trying to take my data from looking like:

```
|SalesID|ItemSequence|ItemCodes|ItemType|
|  123  |    000001  |  Sheet  | Main   |
|  123  |    000002  | Blue Dye| Add on |
|  123  |    000003  |Cut Sheet| Add on |
|  123  |    000004  |  Sheet  | Main   |
|  123  |    000005  |Cut Sheet| Add on |
```

To looking like

```
|SalesID|ItemSequence|ItemCodes| Addon1  | Addon2  |
|  123  |    000001  |  Sheet  |Blue Dye |Cut Sheet|
|  123  |    000002  |  Sheet  |Cut Sheet|         |
```

I am currently trying to do it with an IIf statement that is not working very well.

```
IIf([ItemSequence] = "000001" and [ItemType] = "Main", IIf([ItemSequence] =   
"000002" and [ItemType] = "Add on", [ItemCodes] = [Addon1] and
IIf([ItemSequence] = "000003" and [ItemType] = "Main",[Addon2] = "",
[Addon2] = [ItemCodes]......
```

And this already horrifically long IIf statement has to continue on depending on how many Items are listed for the SalesID. I'm looking for a proper way to do this that doesn't involve a 50,000 word IIf statement that probably won't work when completed.

Comment: Access supports [Cross Tab](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304348) Queries Look at the wizard for that type of query it may help you do what you're trying to do here.

Comment: AFAICT, you need to match up each 'Add on' `ItemType` with the "closest previous" row which has 'Main' as `ItemType`.  Is that correct?

Comment: @HansUp That is correct.

Comment: @xQbert The cross tab query is not working out for what I am trying to do.   No matter what I put in as the selected fields it wants me to add in a count formula, or average of some form.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  This is challenging for Access SQL.  Can you add another field to the table to indicate which rows are associated with each 'Main' set?

Comment: @HansUp I would have to do that manually I think? Are you saying to add a column and make the first 'main' set of a salesID number 1, and the second 'main' set be number 2 or something similar?

Comment: Yes, 1 for ItemSequence 000001 thru 000003, 2 for ItemSequence 000004 and 000005, and so on.